# Batch - Using findstr to read a file entry and output if it is less than a variable

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I'm trying to read a text file using findstr to output only specific characters based on whether the value is less than my predefined number value. Here is a line from the text file that i am trying to read:

```
BW6556 *NULL* 1 6 1406922741 1407046596 1415081796 0 845292618 3 3 5 5 0 8 1024

BW6657 *NULL* 1 6 1408817016 1408817016 1416852216 0 193816666 2 2 5 5 0 0 1024
```

I need an expression that looks at the above line and does the following:

1. looks at the long number on each line that starts at character 41 and ends on character 50
2. If that number is GREATER THAN 1 and LESS THAN my variable number %expirydate% then write out characters 1-7 to a new file.
3. Does the same thing on every line in the text file!

Any ideas?

Comment: what about the spaces between numbers?The requiested number will have a space in it...

Comment: What is the highest value that the number can be?  Are there literal nulls in the lines/

Answer (score 2):

That cannot be done with FINDSTR. First off, FINDSTR cannot numerically compare numbers. Second, FINDSTR cannot return a substring from a line.

It can be solved using FOR /F to parse the space delimited list of values. Note that this solution is not based on character position.

***EDIT:*** *Major rewrite to handle possibility of number larger than 2147483647. Also, my original code failed if it had zeros in the middle of the number*

This solution assumes all lines have 10 digits in the 7th token (position 41). I enclose the values in quotes within the IF comparison to force it to do a text comparison instead of a numeric comparison. This will work properly as long as all values have exactly 10 digits.

```
set "num=0000000000%expirydate%"
set "num=%num:~-10%"
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,7" %%A in ("test.txt") do (
  if "%%C" gtr "0000000001" if "%%C" lss "%expirydate%" (echo %%A )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I look at your example and take character 41 to 50 from the first line it gives me: "141508179", but that string is ten characters long; "1415081796" and it doesn't look like a date.

Here you have a VBScript which extracts numbers bigger than 200000000 and places them in a new file.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\input.txt", ForReading)   
Do While objFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    extractednr = Mid(strLine,41,9)
    If (extractednr > 200000000) Then
        strContents = strContents & extractednr & vbCrLf
    End If
Loop
objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\output.txt", true)
objFile.WriteLine strContents
objFile.Close
```

Comment: Thanks for this but i dont really understand VB script so can't manupulate this :( i really need the script to check whether the numbers between characters 41-51 are larger than my %expirydate% variable and if so then to output the first 7 characters of that line to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions..You want the number BEFORE or AFTER spaces are cleared?Are you sure that the these are exact end and start charaters ? What can be max value of the numbers ? Can it be more than 2147483647 - the max integer value?If it is - can be a string comparison be executed instead?

```
@echo off

set /a variable=2147483647
set "val_file=number.txt"
set "new_file=new.txt"

break>"%new_file%"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "useback delims=" %%# in ("%val_file%") do (
    set "line=%%#"
    set line=!line:~40,10!
    set /a number=!line: =!
    rem echo !number! !variable!
    if !number! GTR 1 if !number! LSS !variable! (echo(!number!)>>"%new_file%"

)
```

Comment: In the example above the number i want to make the comparison too is: 1415081796 Yes they are exact start and end characters. Max value of the numbers would be 9999999999 not sure if a string comparison can be executed? if it deals with numbers then yes i suppose... :S